# unknown error verifying number Error instance: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, ionic-framework

i am trying to use a plugin for phone auth on ionic that i found this link: https://github.com/sajTempler/IonicFirebasePhoneAuth, by default the country code was hardcoded to 47, so i changed it to 55, which is my CC, however i am unsure if there's something wrong with the plugin, or did i just didn't type it the number properly, because everytime i try to register my phone number i get the following error on the chrome inspect page

> registerPhone err unknown error verifying number Error instance: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException

Now here's the code

Login.ts

```
   import {Component, ViewChild, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import {IonicPage, NavController, AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';
    import {AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth';
    import {Firebase} from '@ionic-native/firebase';
    import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

    /**
     * Generated class for the LoginPage page.
     *
     * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
     * Ionic pages and navigation.
     */

    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-login',
      templateUrl: 'login.html',
    })
    export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

      @ViewChild('phoneNumber') phoneNumber;

      constructor(
        private navCtrl: NavController,
        private fireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
        private alertCtrl: AlertController,
        private fire: Firebase,
      ) {
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        console.log('LoginPage ngOnInit');
        this.fireAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
          if (!auth) {
            return;
          }

          auth.getIdToken()
            .then((token: string) => {
              console.log('LoginPage getIdToken token', token);
              if (token) {
                this.doLogin();
              }
            });
        });
      }

      // tslint:disable-next-line
      private registerPhone(): void {
        console.log('registerPhone');
        const phone = '+55' + this.phoneNumber.value;
        console.log('registerPhone phone', phone);
        this.fire.verifyPhoneNumber(phone, 120)
          .then((res) => {
            const {verificationId} = res;
            console.log('registerPhone verificationId', verificationId);
            this.showPrompt(verificationId);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log('registerPhone err', err);
          })
      }

      private async verifyCode(code: string, verificationId: string) {
        try {
          const credential = await firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, code);
          await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
            .then(() => {
              this.doLogin();
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.error('LoginPage verifyCode signInWithCredential err', err);
            })
        } catch (err) {
          console.error('LoginPage verifyCode err', err);
        }
      }

      private showPrompt(verificationId: string) {
        let promptCode = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'Verify',
          message: 'Type code that was received via SMS',
          inputs: [
            {
              name: 'code',
              placeholder: 'Code'
            },
          ],
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'Cancel',
              handler: data => {
                return;
              }
            },
            {
              text: 'Verify',
              handler: data => {
                this.verifyCode(data.code, verificationId);
              }
            }
          ]
        });
        promptCode.present();
      }

      private doLogin(): void {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage');
      }
    }
```

Login.html

```
<!--
  Generated template for the LoginPage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
-->
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

  <div class="login-verify" id="recaptcha-container"></div>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>+55</ion-label>
      <ion-input #phoneNumber type="tel" maxlength="11"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>

<ion-footer class="login-footer">
  <button full ion-button class="login-btn" (click)="registerPhone()">Go</button>
</ion-footer>
```

Here's the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvEft.jpg

Everytime i try, i do: +CC operator number, phone number, which is 11 numbers in total.

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/unknown-error-verifying-number-error-instance-com-google-firebase-auth-firebaseauthexception-error-code-error-app-not-authorized/116772/2

Comment: I already altered the SHA-1 Key, that isn't the issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the project_id in your Android app google-services.json file is the same as the Firebase project for which you enabled Google Sign In Authentication? If that is the case and you have not edited the google-services.json file, you can file a support ticket to Firebase.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32058272)